# Java jSoup - get data from web tables

Tags: java, jsoup

I am looking to get data from this webpage: http://www.sportinglife.com/greyhounds/racecards/29-10-2014/belle-vue

I have been using jSoup and Java, but can't seem to get the data I am looking for. I need the times of each race (Jump to: 14:18 14:37 14:57 15:17 15:38 15:58 16:18 16:37 16:57 17:17 17:33 17:47 18:04 18:18) and the link that each of them refers to.

I then need to go to each link and print out the 6 dogs in each race.

So the output would look like:

```
14:18
1 Golden Light
2 Always Late
3 Redley Rooster
4 Redstone Bo Dhu
5 Ballymac Oprah
6 Ballyhill Slide
```

For each race.

My current code is below, and uses jSoup to extract the runners from the race - but I can't seem to do the first step of getting the race "times" and links to each race page so I can loop through the links and output the runners for each race.

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
            "http://www.sportinglife.com/greyhounds/racecards/29-10-2014/belle-vue/card/834800").get();

    Element tableHeader = doc.select("tbody").first();
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
        // Here you can do something with each element
            String dog = element.select("td:eq(0)").text();
            String race = element.select("td:eq(2)").text();
            data.put(dog, race);
            System.out.println(dog + " " + race);

        }
```

Any help is very much appreciated.... thanks!
Rob

Comment: Why do you want the links they refer to?

Comment: I need the links they refer to so that I can loop through the links, and output the 6 dogs for each race. Unless there is an easier way to do this just from the first page?

Comment: You could loop through all sections. Every section contains the time, plus a table. Every row of this table contains the information you need about the dogs

Comment: Oh right I see. Do you know how I would do this using jSoup? I'm not too sure on how to loop through the sections... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your page, the race information are not directly in the second `TD` but in a link (`a`) in the second `TD`, then you need to replace :

```
 String race = element.select("td:eq(2)").text();
```

with :

```
 String race = element.select("td:eq(2) a").text();
```